# How can I serialize a List<> of classes that I've created

Tags: c#, xml, save, xml-serialization

I have the following code:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
    saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xml";
    var resultDialog = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this);
    if (resultDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        SerializeObject(ListaDeBotoes, fileName);
    }
}

public void SerializeObject(List<MyButton> serializableObjects, string fileName)
{
    if (serializableObjects == null) { return; }

    try
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObjects.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObjects);
            stream.Position = 0;
            xmlDocument.Load(stream);
            xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log exception here
    }
}
```

My objective is to save this list of `MyButton`s, that is my own class (it is a control too if this matter), in a way that i could re-open it on the future. But this way is not working it stops at: `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObjects.GetType());` and the catch exception is called... Any suggestions?

Comment: ...what's in the actual exception

Comment: "Any suggestions?" You might want to cast a glance at json.net; despite the name, I think it [de]serializes XML as well as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

Usings.....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Functions....

```
    private void Serialize<T>(T data)
    {

        // Use a file stream here.
        using (TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
        {
            // Construct a SoapFormatter and use it  
            // to serialize the data to the stream.
            XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            try
            {
                // Serialize EmployeeList to the file stream
                SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }

    private T Deserialize<T>() where T : new()
    {
        //List<Employee> EmployeeList2 = new List<Employee>();
        // Create an instance of T
        T ReturnListOfT = CreateInstance<T>();


        // Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
        using (FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            // Construct a XmlSerializer and use it  
            // to serialize the data from the stream.
            XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            try
            {
                // Deserialize the hashtable from the file
                ReturnListOfT = (T)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message));
            }

        }
        // return the Deserialized data.
        return ReturnListOfT;
    }

    // function to create instance of T
    public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }
```

Usage....

```
Serialize(dObj); // dObj is List<YourClass>

List<YourClass> deserializedList = Deserialize<List<YourClass>>();
```

Your object will be written\read to\from a file called test.xml that you can modify to suit....

Hope that helps....

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

An example class to hold your values for each MyButton object might look something like this......

```
public partial class PropertiesClass
{
    public string colorNow { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(Color.Black.ToArgb()));
    public string backgroundColor { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(Color.Black.ToArgb()));
    public string externalLineColor { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(Color.DarkBlue.ToArgb()));
    public string firstColor { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(Color.Goldenrod.ToArgb()));
    public string secondColor { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(Color.DarkGoldenrod.ToArgb()));
    public string mouseEnterColor { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(Color.PaleGoldenrod.ToArgb()));
    public string doubleClickColor { get; set; } = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(Color.Gold.ToArgb()));

    public bool shouldIChangeTheColor { get; set; } = true;
    public bool selectedToMove { get; set; } = true;
    public bool selectedToLink { get; set; } = true;
}
```

Usage...

```
        List<PropertiesClass> PropertiesClasses = new List<PropertiesClass>();
        PropertiesClass PropertiesClass = new PropertiesClass();
        PropertiesClasses.Add(PropertiesClass);
        Serialize(PropertiesClasses);
```

Comment: Ok, but in the line `XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));` the exception `There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[MyButtonCode.MyButton]'.` happens. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: Need to see the classes (MyButton) that you are passing to XmlSerializer

Comment: in your code (posted in the question) you are passing 'List<MyButton>' to SerializeObject function. I needed to see the code for 'MyButton'. Please update your question with the code for 'MyButton' class

Comment: You cant serialize a class that inherits from UserControl.. you will need to define classes that describe the properties you need for the control (MyButton) instead of serializing the actual control. Then you can set the properties for each MyButton at runtime by reading the values back in from a file....

Comment: I have modified my answer with an example class of how you might serialize your values for each MyButton object to XML...

Answer (score 0):

If thats not a homework or study stuff you better use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize your classes. Reinvent the well is probably gonna cost you more time.